# No image occure from JSON

Tags: java, android, base64

I have a webservice that returns a json object with a decodes image

Link to JSON:

[JSON OBJECT](http://surfkid.redio.de/getChannelImage?session_id=ac9892e83e10994b7de728e44450808e&channel_id=1)

My Java Code in a handler:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){
              @Override
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                pd.cancel();
                 if (msg.obj.toString()!= null)
                 {
                 JSONParse json = null;
                 try {
                    Log.e("XXX",msg.obj.toString());
                     json = new JSONParse(msg.obj.toString());
                        String im = json.getChannelImage();
                        im = im.split("\r")[0];
                        if (!im.equals(null))
                        {
                            byte[] decodedString = Base64Coder.decode(im);
                            Log.e("Byte", decodedString.toString());
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
                            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception ("no image avaibale");
                        }


                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast toast ;
                            toast =     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.getMessage(), 500);
                            Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                 }
                 else
                 {

                   runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast toast ;
                        toast =     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", 500);

                        toast.show();
                    }
                });
                 }
              }
              };
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/mainscreen" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Selected Channel" android:gravity="center"></TextView>



<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that no image is shown.

LOG:

```
02-09 14:08:05.833: ERROR/XXX(438): {"responseData":{"image":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAsUAAADMCAYAAACbW975AAAABmJLR0QA\/wD\/AP+gvaeTAAAAB3RJ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
02-09 14:08:06.033: ERROR/Byte(438): [B@43dc08a0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you split String? You need all image data.

```
 String im = json.getChannelImage();
                    im = im.split("\r")[0];
```

Try to delete \r\n symbols from json String and decode it all.

```
 String im = json.getChannelImage();
                    im = im.replace("\r\n", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a solution for you but I don't understand why you are using JSON to return an image. You really should just return an image in binary format. There is no advantage on to what you are doing. Instead just load the image. If the image is not on disk, then the server can load the image from some database and flush the content to outputstream. You just have to set content type correctly.